# using simple node app, localhost not sending data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a newbie so be kind. I've been trying to learn passport via an online tutorial (this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1ktxiqyiLA), github [here](https://github.com/bradtraversy/loginapp)) and as far as I can tell I've recreated the code verbatim but I'm getting an error that the localhost didn't send any data. My full code is [here](https://github.com/jehartman/passportPractice). I'm pasting some code below but I'm honestly unsure which piece of code to post since I don't know where the error is occurring.

Here's the server app:

```html
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

//Init app
var app = express();

//View engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());

//set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//express session middleware
app.use(session({
 secret: 'secret',
 saveUninitialized: true,
 resave: true
}));

//passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//validator middleware-- this code is straight from the validator github page
app.use(expressValidator({
 errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
   var namespace = param.split(',')
   , root = namespace.shift()
   , formParam = root;

  while(namespace.length) {
   formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
  }
  return {
   param  : formParam,
   msg  : msg,
   value : value 
  };
 }
}));

//connect flash middleware
app.use(flash());

//global variables for flash messages
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

//set port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
 console.log('Server started on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Here's the form:

```html
<h2 class="page-header">Register</h2>
<form method="post" action="/users/register">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password2">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here's the user js:

```html
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//register
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
 res.render('register');
});

//login
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
 res.render('login');
});

//register user
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
 var name = req.body.name;
 var email = req.body.email;
 var username = req.body.username;
 var password = req.body.password;
 var password2 = req.body.password2;
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do that doesn't work?

Comment: Oh man, I'm sorry. I'm trying to submit test data from the web form.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: you are actually not doing anything on the post('/register'..)

You should save your model and return it if successful, something like this:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', email: 'string' });
var User = mongoose.model('User', schema);

//register user
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;

  var user = new User({ name: name,  email: email});
  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(user);
  });
});
```

Of course you would define your model on a separate folder and import it to where it fits.

Comment: Thanks. This was just a test post to generate a console log message. I wasn't capturing data yet, just testing to see if the form would post to the server. It doesn't. At this point in the tutorial there is no additional code covered, so perhaps the instructor is operating from code he has not yet shown.

Comment: I've noticed your console.log is outside the post register, it should be inside! only what is within the scope of the post register will be called once your form is submitted.

Comment: God bless you. I was assuming the form did not submit because I didn't get the test log, but I had the console log in the wrong place. That also solves my second problem, why name wasn't defined. Thanks!

Comment: I did but it doesn't show because I'm a newbie to the forums. Thanks again.